# What does おつかれさまでしたどぞ means

Tags: words, meaning, usage

I know the meaning of おつかれさまでした and どぞ but when they are put together I really can't get what it really means. Does it have a positive or negative meaning?

To make it clear: one time one of my officemate went home and it is a tradition in our company that when you went home late you need to say goodbye to your Japanese superiors, so when he said "お先に失礼いたします" the other Japanese superios replied おつかれさまでした but one of them said おつかれさまでしたどぞ then laugh like he is trolling or mocking my officemate. Of course it is only from my point of view so I want to know what it really means.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, 「おつかれさまでした**どぞ**」 is not a common phrase at all.  From your description, however, I am pretty sure what was going on.

The Japanese counterpart of "***Over***" used in wireless communications to mean "a message is complete" is 「**どうぞ**」 and it is often pronounced like 「**どぞ**」 to shorten it.

Thus, I would think that the boss was kidding by speaking like he was on a radio circuit.

Comment: How would one say "over and out"?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I want to know that too but they will probably not reply... I asked them something in comments before and they did not reply. But if you ask it here on the site I will upvote your question! \\(^o^)/